# Array is empty once filled? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am relatively new to Java. I am trying to read a .csv file and make some calculations on it. I succesfully managed to read the file and get the data in the form of a String structured as the csv, with " " (spaces) instead of commas, then I'd like to turn the number (strings) into doubles and stock them in the array.

The dataArray is declared in the class as follows:

```
public double dataArray[][];
```

For some reason i get an empty array (an array full only of 0.0) after having run the following method to fill it:

```
//Store value into the array
public void toArray()
{
    try
    {
        int nrows = this.text.split("\n").length;
        int ncolumns =this.text.split("\n")[0].split(" ").length;
        //System.out.println(nrows);
        //System.out.println(ncolumns);
        this.dataArray = new double[nrows][ncolumns];
        for(int i=0; i<nrows ;i++)
        {
            for(int k=1; k<(ncolumns-1);k++)
            {
                double number = Double.parseDouble(this.text.split("\n")[i].split(" ")[k]);  //Double.parseDouble(this.text.split("\n")[i].split(" ")[k]);
                this.dataArray[i][k] = number;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried several fix, even using other methods in this method but haven't find a solution yet..

EDIT: Fixed k which was wrong

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Did you check, that `nrows` and `ncolumns` are correct?

Comment: What is the value of `this.text`?

Comment: This won't solve the problem but you should split your text only once instead of splitting it each time

Comment: Btw. you should save intermediate steps in local variables. E.g. the result of `this.text.split("\n")` and `this.text.split("\n")[i].split(" ")` (in the loop).

Comment: @MPirious nrows and ncolumns are correct, checked! Let me try this solution with intermediate variables.

Comment: You don't get an exception, do you?

Comment: test is a string which goes like this " 0.3 0.4 0.6\n 0.4 0.5 0.7\n ..." it goes on for 200 rows, my idea was: split for "\n" and get the line, then split for " " and get the numbers (except the 0th element which is a space and which I fixed by editing k)

Comment: @MPirious no exceptions

Comment: Can you put the CSV file to pastebin? So we can run (and debug) your example.

Comment: Are you aware, that you skip the first and last column?

Comment: @Mpirious using intermediate variables does not seem to work.. Let me paste a copy of the .csv...Yes I skipped the first column to avoid the blank space " " which comes from the second split.

Comment: Somehow I managed to make it work, thanks everyone, sorry for the silly question, I'm still a newbie at Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of debugging your code, I propose you a working snippet that does what you need :

```
public void toArray() {
    String[] split = this.text.split("\n");
    this.data = new double[split.length][];
    for (int i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++) {
        String[] cols = split[i].split("\\s+");
        data[i] = new double[cols.length];
        for (int j=0 ; j<cols.length ; j++)
            data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(cols[j]);
    }
}
```

Tested on : `text = "1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n9  10   11"`

Output : `data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [9.0, 10.0, 11.0]]`